# Why won't my code draw characters to screen?

Tags: c++, text, bitmap, vga

I'm working on a little operating system, and I've gotten to the part where I want to draw characters to screen. I'm having issues getting my code to run (which might just be due to my rusty C++ skills), and when I do, I don't see the requested character on screen. I copied an 8x8 ASCII character bitmap, and tried to use code from [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Fonts) as a base for my text-displaying function. Here's my C++ code so far:

```
#define LOCHAR 32
#define HICHAR 127
#define FONT_HEIGHT 8
//bitmap
unsigned char font[HICHAR-LOCHAR+1][FONT_HEIGHT] = {
{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,0x00,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x05,0x00,0x00 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x0F,0x0F,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x07,0x07,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x09,0x04,0x02,0x09 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x0D,0x07,0x0B },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x02,0x00,0x00 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x02,0x02,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x04,0x04,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x07,0x02,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x07,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x00 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x04,0x02,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x02,0x02,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x04,0x03,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x06,0x04,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x05,0x07,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x03,0x04,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x01,0x07,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x04,0x02,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x07,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x07,0x04,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x06,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x02,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x00,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x04,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x06,0x00,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0F,0x09,0x0A,0x0F },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x05,0x07,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x07,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x01,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x05,0x05,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x03,0x01,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x03,0x01,0x01 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x05,0x07,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x02,0x02,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x04,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x03,0x03,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x07,0x07,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x05,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x07,0x01 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x07,0x0F },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x03,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x01,0x06,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x02,0x02,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x05,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x05,0x03,0x01 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x07,0x07,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x02,0x05,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x07,0x02,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x04,0x02,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x02,0x02,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,0x04,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x04,0x04,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x05,0x00,0x00 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0F },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00,0x00 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x07,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x07,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x01,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x07,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x07,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x02,0x07,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x07,0x04,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x07,0x05,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x05,0x03,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x02,0x02,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x07,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x05,0x03,0x01 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x05,0x06,0x04 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0x01,0x01 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x02,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x06,0x02,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x05,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x07,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x07,0x07 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x02,0x05 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x06,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x02,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x03,0x02,0x06 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03,0x06,0x02,0x03 },{ 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x07,0x01,0x00 }};

void draw_pixel(int pos_x, int pos_y, unsigned char colour)
{
    unsigned char* location = (unsigned char*)0xA0000 + 320 * pos_y + pos_x;
    *location = colour;
}
 
void draw_char(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int color)
{
    int cx,cy;
    int mask[8]={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
    unsigned char *glyph[8]=font[(int)c-LOCHAR];
 
    for(cy=0;cy<8;cy++){
        for(cx=0;cx<8;cx++){
            if((int)glyph[cy]&mask[cx]==true){
                draw_pixel(color,x+cx,y+cy-12);
            }
        }
    }
}

extern "C" void main(){

    for(int h = 0; h<200; h++)
    {
        for(int w = 0; w<320; w++)
        {    
            draw_pixel(w,h,h);
        }
    }
    draw_char(97, 100, 100, 4);
    
    return;
}
```

As for troubleshooting I've done so far, I've modified the original 'draw_char' function to suit my needs as best I can, but with my little experience with C++, I'm sure I just made it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The following statement is not what you expect:

```
if((int)glyph[cy] & mask[cx] == true) ...
```

Aggressively isolating all operators with parentheses, this translates to:

```
((int)(glyph[cy])) & ( (mask[cx]) == true )
```

In other words, the value `mask[cx] == true` is being calculated first and then used for the bitwise-AND. That's because the operator `==` has a higher precedence than `&`.

You *could* do this if you must (but don't, and read on):

```
if (((int)glyph[cy] & mask[cx]) == true) ...
```

The problem here is now you're directly comparing an integer to a boolean, relying on the compiler to explicitly cast. Not only that, but you're comparing to a *true* value which is something we tend to avoid (historically, any non-zero value is considered true). You will find that most production code either omits boolean comparisons altogether, or will always favor comparison phrased with respect to *false* values.

That might sound pedantic, and if so then that's unfortunate but also fine. Here's the upshot though... All you actually need is this:

```
if (glyph[cy] & mask[cx]) ...
```

Now, let's look at `glyph`. I really don't know why your compiler isn't screaming at you here. It's wrong, and is likely also responsible for your program behaving weird. You've defined it as follows:

```
// incorrect: you didn't want an array of 8 pointers!!
unsigned char *glyph[8] = font[(int)c - LOCHAR];
```

The correct definition is:

```
const unsigned char *glyph = font[(int)c - LOCHAR];
```

A final note on your `mask` table. It's not really necessary, unless you plan on doing something fancy with it. You can just as easily implement it with shifts:

```
if (glyph[cy] & ((unsigned char)1U << cx)) ...
```